# ¿Cuándo se utiliza «primer» y «primero»?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, números

¿Por qué se dice *primero* en *primero plato* y no *primer* como en *primer numero*?  ¿Cuál es la diferencia?  Estoy confundido

Comment: I'm no native speaker, but I've been living in Spain for 10 years now. I've never heard *Primero plato*, but either *Primer plato* or *Primero*. Where have you seen/heard *Primero plato*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ¿Por qué se dice primero en 'primero plato' ...?

No se dice, "primero plato" (¿dónde lo has visto?), se dice "primer plato". La regla es: el adjetivo "**primero**" toma la forma abreviada (apócope) "**primer**" cuando va delante de un sustantivo masculino.

Answer (score 8):

Una cosa importante es que hay que tomar en cuenta el género del sustantivo.  Como dice [leonbloy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3351/106), es usa **primer** solo si es masculino.  En caso el sustantivo sea de género femenino, siempre se usa **primera**.

Comment: La primera planta, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 3):

Se usa `primer` y `tercer` cuando son sustantivos masculinos en singular pero el resto se dice normal. Ejemplo:
El primer plato
El segundo Plato
El tercer Plato
El Cuarto plato...y asi todos iguales

Answer (score 1):

La frase ''primero plato'' suena a un anglofono que esta aprendiendo español. No es correcto. Lo correcto es `primer plato`.

Answer (score 1):

Quizas hayas visto en el menu de un restaurante "De primero" (as a first course). Pero la palabra primero va siempre después del sustantivo.

Answer (score 1):

Según la RAE

https://www.rae.es/dpd/ordinales

"4. Los ordinales primero y tercero se apocopan en las formas primer y tercer cuando preceden a un sustantivo masculino, aunque entre ambos se interponga otra palabra; esta apócope también se produce cuando forman parte de ordinales compuestos: el primer ministro, mi tercer gran amor; el vigesimoprimer aniversario. La apócope es opcional si el ordinal aparece antepuesto y coordinado con otro adjetivo: mi primero y último amor o mi primer y último amor. Constituye un arcaísmo, que debe evitarse en el habla culta actual, la apócope de estos ordinales ante sustantivos femeninos: la primer vez, la tercer casa."