# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1910 (note 1 of 3)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1910 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are three entries.

Here is the first one (split into three images):

[image]

[image]

[image]

The transcribed text so far (I have not attempted the signiatures yet):

> Competiendo este individuo en actual compromiso en fin de agosto
> actual lo hasta y xxx  xxx por el Señor  1º Jefe del a Comandancia xxx
> por 4 años con opción xxx xxx la leyriguette toda veo que xxx la
> circúlela las prevenías y ha resultado xxx del recovar inmiento  xxx
> que al afecta ha fin xxx. Esta c compromiso xxx xxx en lo que xxx
> fecha hoy premiso a reserva de lo que la Millinencion  General xxx en
> de fin xxx enpxxx a estinqino y mismo en 1º de Septiembre de este año
> y coterminara en fin de xxx 1914 xxx la presente hasta en pruebo diez
> conformidad con el Jefe  y tesstiga que Director en Sevilla.
>
> El 2º Jefe

I admit that I have found it quite hard to transcribe (it is not good!). I guess for someone comfortable with Spanish you can pick out the word patterns easier. What I can see if my Great Grandfathers signiature on the right! So I guess this is a significant note.

I have also stuggled to work out where sentences start and stop. And I don't actually see a "date" for the note.

---

#### Translation

At the moment I have the following translation based on suggestions provided in answers:

> Having completed his current commitment at the end of August, this
> individual requested and was granted by the 1st Chief of the Command
> the reenlistment for 4 years with the option of the benefits granted
> by the law in force, given that he meets the circumstances foreseen
> and has been useful in the optional examination he has undergone for
> this purpose. This commitment has been admitted as far as the award is
> concerned, subject to the final decision of the General Comptroller's
> Office, which will begin to expire on 1st September this year and will
> end at the end of August 1914. Signing this note in proof of his
> agreement with the undersigned Chief and witnesses in Seville.
>
> The 2nd Chief

---

#### Update 1

I have updated the translation based on the combined efforts of both answers. I think the translation is clear and understandable, with one exception. The phrase **begin to *expire* on** does not seem right to me. Thoughts?

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1910 (note 2 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39440/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1910 (note 3 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39443/28260)

Comment: "begin to expire" is a strange way of putting things but it's based on the concept that a period of time begins to expire, it's closer to its end day by day, from the moment that it's started. It's an archaic and burocratic way of saying just "starting". "begin to expire" = "starting". "starting on 1st September (1910) and ending in August 1914"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestions

> **Cumpliendo** este individuo **su** actual compromiso en fin de agosto
> actual, **solicitó y le fue concedido** por el Señor 1º Jefe de la Comandancia **el reenganche**
> por 4 años con opción **a los beneficios que concede** la ley **vigente** toda **vez** que **reune las
> circunstancias prevenidas** y ha resultado **útil** del **reconocimiento facultativo**
> que al **efecto** ha **sufrido**. **Este** compromiso **le ha sido admitido** en lo que **respecta al permiso?**, a reserva de lo que la **Intervención** General **resuelva en
> definitiva** empezando a xxxx **su servicio?** en 1º de Septiembre de este año
> y **lo terminará** en fin **de agosto de** 1914. **Firmando** la presente **carta?** en **prueba de su**
> conformidad con el Jefe y **testigos** que **suscriben** en Sevilla.
>
> Firmas

Comment: Thanks. Where you have **?** is that because you are not sure of the word you selected?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That's right

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I agree with "extinguir el mismo" and "nota" suggested by gparis

Comment: And the other two? "1er" and "premio"?

Comment: 1er and 1º are synonyms in Spanish. I think that it's not relevant if the actual little letter is just an "o" or is an "er". I'm not sure about "premio".

Comment: Thanks. See the updated translation.

Comment: Also, according to my wordprocessor **reune** needs to be **reúne**.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Your wordprocessor is right.

Comment: I wonder if the unsure word is actually **las servicio**? It then translates as **This commitment has been admitted as far as his service is concerned, subject to the final decision...**.

Comment: "las" doesn't match "servicio" in gender nor number. It may be "el" or "su".

Comment: Ok, we'll see if there are any more suggestions for that word. At the moment I have left it as **premio** as I don't know if **servicio** is better or not.

Answer (score 2):

Based on RubioRic suggestions:

> Cumpliendo este individuo su actual compromiso en fin de agosto
> actual, solicitó y le fue concedido por el Señor **1er** Jefe de la
> Comandancia el reenganche por 4 años con opción a los beneficios que
> concede la ley vigente toda vez que reúne las circunstancias
> prevenidas y ha resultado útil del reconocimiento facultativo que al
> efecto ha sufrido. Este compromiso le ha sido admitido en lo que
> respecta al **premio**, a reserva de lo que la Intervención General
> resuelva en definitiva empezando a **extinguir el mismo** en 1º de
> Septiembre de este año y lo terminará en fin de agosto de 1914.
> Firmando la presente **nota** en prueba de su conformidad con el Jefe
> y testigos que suscriben en Sevilla.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have updated the translation in the question. See what you think. By the way, what is the difference between **1o** and **1er**?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I suspect this is the writer distinguishing between _primer_ and _primero_. This Q&A explains the usage https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/cu%c3%a1ndo-se-utiliza-primer-y-primero