# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1910 (note 2 of 3)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1910 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are three entries.

Here is the second one:

[image]

The transcribed text so far:

> Según certificada expedido por el Excmo. Señor Presidente del Cuerpo
> de Aliuish fecha 18 de Mayo año maninal, le ha aido concordada a este
> individuo, el uso de la xxx conmemoración del 1er centenario de  las
> xxx Rey de Gemma.

I know I have some unknown words there! :)

---

#### Translation

This is the translation based on the suggested transcription in the answer.

> According to the certificate issued by the President of the
> Council of Ministers on 18th May of the year Marginal, this individual
> has been awarded the Commemorative Medal of the 1st centenary of the
> sieges of Gerona.

I still think that the user of the word **Marginal** is a little odd. At least, it is odd in the way it has been automatically put in the translation.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1910 (note 1 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39436/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1910 (note 3 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39443/28260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions

> Según **certificado** expedido por el Excmo. Señor Presidente del **Consejo de Ministros** fecha 18 de Mayo año **marginal**, le ha **sido concedida** a este
> individuo, el uso de la **Medalla Conmemorativa** del 1er centenario de **[los
> sitios de Gerona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_siege_of_Girona)**.

You can check the medal [here](https://www.coleccionesmilitares.com/medallas/texto/odm5.htm). In that site you can find also this explanation

> Otorgada a los descendientes de los heroicos defensores de Gerona y a
> cuantas personas hayan contribuido de algún modo a las fiestas del
> Centenario y erección del monumento

Probably your ancestor were on duty in Gerona/Girona during the conmemoration of the centenary.

[image: Medalla del centenario de los sitios de Gerona]

Note: The word **marginal** was suggested by @wimi, meaning that the year is the same that the one written in the margin/margen of the sheet. I agree with him.

Comment: @wimi 4 seconds because I was searching additional info about the medal ;-P

Comment: These things happen :D . The remaining xxxxx might be "año marginal", meaning "año escrito en el margen". Seems like a weird use of "marginal", but nothing else comes to mind.

Comment: @wimi I think that you're right about the use of "marginal".

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link to the medal! If I read the linked article correctly the event itself was on **28 de enero de 1910**. And the award of these medals followed later in the May. I wonder what happened to his medal. Hmm! I undated the translation in the question. Still not sure about **marginal**.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That date corresponds to the Royal Decree that awarded the medal but not to the event itself. Such event probably was celebrated at december 1909

Comment: BTW it is interesting that my mums mothers ancestry is all up in Corella! But we are dealing with my mumds fathers ancestry here.