# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1910 (note 3 of 3)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1910 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are three entries.

Here is the third and final one. ( will start on 1911 either tonight or tomorrow).

[image]

I think I might have already transcribed this correctly but I am still asking the question for consistency of the notes. The transcribed text so far:

> Todo el año prestando sus servicios en el puesto de Herrera.

---

#### Translation

The current translation:

> All year round serving at the Herrera post.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1910 (note 1 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39436/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1910 (note 2 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39440/28260)

Comment: I think that you've nailed it.

Comment: @RubioRic Great! 1911 has two entries. But the second one looks word for word the same as this one. So tomorrow (or tonight) there will be only one note for 1911 to deal with.

Comment: I think you need to hire a professional. Figuring out handwriting is off topic here.

Comment: @Lambie, all due respect, you feel the need to chime in now with such a comment, after the whole document was completed nearly a year ago? On a personal note I was very grateful for all those who assisted me.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I didn't look at the date but the question came up on the head of the queue. I still think you misused the site. I do manuscript deciphering myself but not here. There are specific sites for paleography.

Answer (score 0):

Todo el año prestando sus servicios en el **fuerte** de Herrera.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But if you look here you will see that it is **puesto**: https://www.guardiacivil.es/es/institucional/directorio/sevilla/puesto_de_herrera.html

Comment: I understand, but regarding the text, if you look closely, it is more looking like an f than a p in that word, specially if you compare it to the p that occurs previously.

Comment: But it also needs to take into account: 1. The fact this is a Civil Guard building and not a military, 2. There are several notes referring to Herrera which show it to be **puesto**.

Comment: I think that if it were an "f", the "u" would have three strokes and look more like an "m"...

Answer (score 0):

**Cuestión**: El texto transcrito hasta ahora es

Todo el año prestando sus servicios en el puesto de Herrera.

Desde mi punto de vista, la transcripción correcta seria;

**Todo el año prestando sus servicios en el puente de Herrera.**