# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 2 of 5)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1914 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are five entries.

Here is the second one:

[image]

Here is the transcribed text so far:

> En el estado de xxx del 1er xxx 1913, acredita la xxxcion Gral
> [General] de Guerra a este xxx 125 pesetas en xxx de xxx de los xxx
> xxx años del compromiso que xxx.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

---

#### Translation

> In the statement of claim for the 1st Quarter of 1913, the
> Intervention General of War credits this individual with 125 pesetas
> for the expiry of the first two years of the commitment he is serving.
>
> The Major Commander

I understand that his current service period was [01 September 1910 to 31 August 1914](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39436/28260). The first quart of 1913 would be Jan / Feb / Mar. The end of his second year would have been 31 August 1912. How come this information is only being written now, in 1914?

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 1 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39467/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 3 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39472/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 4 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39474/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1914 (note 5 of 5)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39476/28260)

Comment: I've got no real anwser for your second question in relation with the dates. I can only guess that the Spanish Goverment and the Guardia Civil Administration burocracies were very slow. Maybe he can only ask for the retributions of his first 2-years period (1910-1912) at the beginning of the following year (1913) and he received the response and the money, as we can see, in 1914.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestions

> En el estado de **reclamación** del 1er **Trimestre de** 1913, acredita la **Intervención** Gral
> [General] de Guerra a este **indº (individuo)** 125 pesetas en **concepto** de **vencimiento** de los **dos primeros** años
> del compromiso que **sirve**.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the translation to the question and added some initial thoughts that come to mind.